# How can nuisance parameters in Fisher matrix can deteriorate the useful constraints?

Tags: covariance-matrix, fisher-information, matrix-inverse, constraint

I have a Fisher matrix $F$ which has the matrix blocks form like this :

$$
F=\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The block $A$ is the most important block, in the sense the parameters of this block are the parameters that I want really get. The block $D$ is called the "nuisance block", that is to say, it consists of the nuisance parameters which deteriorate the informations of the block $A$. The blokc $B$ and $C$ are the correlations blocks between "important block" $A$ and "nuisance block" $D$.

**Question :** How can I prove mathematically that, by inversing the Fisher matrix $F$, I will get worse constraints (I mean larger variances) on the important parameters (corresponding to $A$ covariance matrix), all of this due to the 3 others blocks ?

**Track followed :**

I know that (1,1) block for inverse of $F$ :
$$
F=\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{bmatrix}
$$

is $(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}$ ([Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement)).

From this, if I take the inverse of Fisher matrix $F$, I will get for covariance matrix (the inverse of $F$), the block (1,1) equal to $(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}$.

How can we be sure that diagonal of this block $(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}$ (which represents the variances of important parameters) will be decreased by the terms "$-BD^{-1}C$" : we should have positive quantities for the diagonal elements of "-$BD^{-1}C$" to make increase the block (1,1) diagonals elements, i.e in order to make worse the constraints, shouldn't we ?

**I make the comparison with the values unmarginalised of block A which have the form into initial Fisher matrix F : a_11 = 1/sigma_1^2, a_22 = 1/sigma_2^2, a_33 = 1/sigma_3^2** ... etc. with sigma_i the standard deviation of each important parameters of block A.

I guess it is difficult to prove that nuisance parameters deteriorate the constraints for block (1,1) of covariance matrix but it would be interesting to have a rigorous demonstration.

Comment: When you say "Fisher matrix", I assume you mean *Fisher information matrix*. Assuming that is correct, then you must have $B=C^T$ and $A$ and $D$ must be positive definite. With these clarifications, result is very easy to prove.

Comment: @GordonSmyth . Thanks for your quick answer. Could you explicit please your reasoning in an answer please ? I didn't manage to prove it with your considerations. Regards

Comment: $C^TD^{-1}C$ is non-negative definite. Result follows immediately.

Comment: @GordonSmyth . Do you mean that block $(A-BD^{-1}C)$ will be "smaller" than block $A$ ? , so the diagonal elements of $(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}$ will be "higher" than $A^{-1}$ (variance will be larger) . It is difficult for me to understand since I am reasoning on diagonal elements whereas I consider all the 4 blocks $A, C^{T}, D$ and $C$, so there are also covariance terms appearing when inversing initial Fisher matrix information $F$.

Comment: @GordonSmyth . If it doesn't bore you, could you do please a small answer but significant. Regards

Comment: Your statements that `a_11 = 1/sigma_1^2` etc are false. You cannot invert individual elements of $A$ like this to get individual variances. You must work with matrices. If you are not familiar with matrix concepts such as positive definiteness then the proof will not be accessible to you.

Comment: Without a detailled answer, this is sure I won't understand. At some point, we have to explain clearly the things instead of just writting a single sentence that is supposed to be understood by everyone. I need explicit operations, it seems the property "positive definite" is true for a vector $x$ such $x^{T}\,(C^{T}D^{-1}C\,x$ is positive. So must I conclude that for each line  of $y=C^{T}$, I will get $y^{T}\,D^{-1}\,y$ element which will be positive, but where does the increasing of constraints of block $A$ occur ? from $(A-C^{T}D^{-1}C)$ block or $((A-C^{T}D^{-1}C))^{-1}$ ?

Comment: I think that this article by [Wittman and Self (2021)](https://escholarship.org/content/qt81b3k4p7/qt81b3k4p7.pdf?t=qqtx5y) might be helpful. Wittman tends to be really good at explaining things. If nothing else you could probably look him up at UC Davis. If you want to laugh you could read about Wittman's hot dog and hot dog bun universe, by way of explaining the [Fisher Matrix for Beginners](http://wittman.physics.ucdavis.edu/Fisher-matrix-guide.pdf).

Comment: It is a bit difficult to see what you mean by 'all due to the three other blocks'. For a matrix of 2 by 2 the inverse of the block $a$ is $$\frac{d}{ad-bc}$$ Now, if $d$ increases, without $bc$ changing, then the inverse will approach $1/a$. So the $d$ does in some way influence the inverse but is this way what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, this is the way I think about it. If we consider for example bc positive, then the inverse is greater than $1/a$, so the constraints will be worse (larger values) than for the unmarginalised block $1/a$. But I woud like to get a rigorous demonstration in the general case, that is to say with 4 blocks of a matrix. By the way, it is intuitive to say oneself that if we have more parameters to constrain, the constraints will be less good that if we have less parameters : is it understable like this ?

Comment: Do you mean *"are the diagonal elements of $A^{-1}$ always smaller than $(A-C^TD^{-1}C)^{-1}$?"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the inverse of the Fisher information is of the form:
$$F^{-1} = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A^{-1}+A^{-1}B(F/A)^{-1}CA^{-1}& ... \\
... & ...
\end{array}\right]$$
where $(F/A) = D - CA^{-1}B$ is the Schur complement of block $D$.

Let's show that diagonal elements of $A^{-1}+A^{-1}B(F/A)^{-1}CA^{-1}$ are bigger than the one of $A^{-1}$, which is equivalent to proving that the diagonal elements of the matrix $R = A^{-1}B(F/A)^{-1}CA^{-1}$ are positive.

Note $p$ the dimension of the upper left block.
We'll just proove that for all $e_i$, vector of the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^p$,
$$e_i^T R e_i \geq 0 .$$ Indeed, as $e_i^T R e_i = R_{ii}$, this will prove what we want.

First note that as $F$ is the Fisher information matrix, it is symmetrical and positive definite. So we get that:

- $A$ is positive definite,
- $B^T = C$,
- Schur complements of $F$, $F/A$ and $F/D$, are symmetrical positive definite.

As $F/A$ is symetrical positive definite, its inverse $(F/A)^{-1}$ also is, and therefore there existe a symetrical definite matrix $Q$ such that $(F/A)^{-1} = Q^T Q$.

Using that, we can write $R$ as
$$R = A^{-1} C^T Q^T QCA^{-1} = \left(Q C A^{-1}\right)^T\left(QCA^{-1}\right)$$

Therefore $$e_i^T R e_i = (QCA^{-1}e_i)^T(QCA^{-1}e_i) = \lVert QCA^{-1}e_i\rVert_2 \geq 0. $$

Hence the result.

Hope this is useful.

---

**Additional note :** Proof that $F^{-1} = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A^{-1}+A^{-1}B(F/A)^{-1}CA^{-1}& ... \\
... & ...
\end{array}\right]$

Write $F$ as $$F = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{array}\right] = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I_p & 0 \\
CA^{-1} & I_q
\end{array}\right] 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A & 0 \\
0 & D - C A^{-1} B
\end{array}\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I_p & A^{-1}B \\
0   & I_q
\end{array}\right]$$
Such that
$$
F^{-1} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I_p & A^{-1}B \\
0   & I_q
\end{array}\right]^{-1}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A & 0 \\
0 & D - C A^{-1} B
\end{array}\right]^{-1}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I_p & 0 \\
CA^{-1} & I_q
\end{array}\right]^{-1}.
$$
It's easy to check that
$$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I_p & 0 \\
CA^{-1} & I_q
\end{array}\right]^{-1}=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I_p & 0 \\
-CA^{-1} & I_q
\end{array}\right]$$
and

$$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I_p & A^{-1}B \\
0 & I_q
\end{array}\right]^{-1}=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I_p & -A^{-1}B \\
0   & I_q
\end{array}\right]$$
and

$$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A & 0 \\
0 & D - CA^{-1}B
\end{array}\right]^{-1}=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A^{-1} & 0 \\
0   & (D - CA^{-1}B)^{-1}
\end{array}\right].$$

Therefore
$$
F^{-1} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I_p & -A^{-1}B \\
0   & I_q
\end{array}\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A^{-1} & 0 \\
0 & (D - C A^{-1} B)^{-1}
\end{array}\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
I_p & 0 \\
-CA^{-1} & I_q
\end{array}\right] = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A^{−1} + A^{−1}B (F/A)^{−1}CA^{-1} & −A^{−1}B(F/A)^{−1}\\
−(F/A)^{−1}CA^{−1} & (F/A)^{−1}
\end{array}\right]
$$
where $F/A = D - CA^{-1}B$ .

Comment: Thanks, I am going to get though it. Just a detail, a closed `$`are missing in (F/A)^{-1}.

Comment: Are you sure that your expression is correct when you write : $$F^{-1} = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A^{-1}+A^{-1}B(F/A)^{-1}CA^{-1}& ... \\
... & ...
\end{array}\right]$$ 

Isn't it rather for the first block : $$(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}$$ ?

Comment: I found this on the Wikipedia page of Schur's complement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Properties . 
I guess then $(A - BD^{-1}C)^{-1} = A^{-1} + A^{-1} B (F/A)^{-1}C A^{-1}$...

Comment: Thanks. I understand the first expression below but not the development which allows to get the second expression of $M^{-1}$ :

Comment: $$
$$- In general, if $A$ is invertible, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
M &=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
I_{p} & 0 \\
C A^{-1} & I_{q}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A & 0 \\
0 & D-C A^{-1} B
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
I_{p} & A^{-1} B \\
0 & I_{q}
\end{array}\right] \\
M^{-1} &=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A^{-1}+A^{-1} B(M / A)^{-1} C A^{-1} & -A^{-1} B(M / A)^{-1} \\
& -(M / A)^{-1} C A^{-1} & (M / A)^{-1}
\end{array}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
Could you help please to do the development to get $M^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @youpilat13 
It's hard to write that in comments so I added a note to my answer. 
But basically you just take the firs equality you wrote, and compute the inverse of all three matrices (inverses of block diagonal and block triangular matrices are easy to compute) and multiply them in the reverse order.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience. Best regards

Comment: I think there is a little error : we have to consider in the decomposition of $F$ the third block as :

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
I_{p} & A^{-1} B \\
0 & I_{q}
\end{array}\right]$$

instead of :

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
I_{p} & D^{-1} B \\
0 & I_{q}
\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: You're right. It's corrected.